# About two combinatorial counting problems.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, combinations

Here are the problems:

1. Suppose $X$ is a set of $n$ elements, and $S_1,...,S_m$ are $m$ subsets of $X$ of average size at least $n/w$. Show that if $m\geq 2kw^k$, then there are $k$ distinct $i_1,...,i_k$ such that $S_{i_1},...,S_{i_k}$ satisfying $|S_{i_1}\cap...\cap S_{i_k}|\geq \frac{n}{2w^k}$.

I've thought about the induction on $k$, but I can't understand these tow coefficients 2----The base case $k=1$ doesn't need these 2's. So I'm wondering whether a stonger statement still holds or not. That is,

Suppose $X$ is a set of $n$ elements, and $S_1,...,S_m$ are $m$ subsets of $X$ of average size at least $n/w$. Show that if $m\geq kw^k$, then there are $k$ distinct $i_1,...,i_k$ such that $S_{i_1},...,S_{i_k}$ satisfying $|S_{i_1}\cap...\cap S_{i_k}|\geq\frac{n}{w^k}$.

2. Suppose $R_1,...R_m\subset\{1,...,n\}$ satisfying that $|R_i|\neq 0$ mod 6 for every $i$, and $|R_i\cap R_j|=0$ mod 6 for every $i\neq j$. Prove that $m\leq 2n$.

I konw the method when the "mod" is a number prime $p$----to use rank inequality of the adjacent matrix on the field $\mathrm{F}_p$. But 6 is not prime, so the rank inequality on $\mathrm{F}_6$ doesn't hold.

Any discussion will be potentially helpful and appreciated.